# How to create one table with multiple tables rows that open/close inside Bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have data which I want to present inside a table. I am using Bootstrap Accordion for this. The challenge is that I have to add the `<table> </table>` tags for the accordion to work properly. I want the open/close to work on individual table rows so that I just have one `<table> </table>` at the start and end of. I am avoiding having so many tables on the same page. The data has hundreds of rows and showing all of it is not feasible. So I want to hide some of it using Bootstrap Accordion without having hundreds of tables as well.

Here is the code. I tried but the table won't work properly with just a single `<table> </table>` tags.

```css
.container {
  width: 1180px;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

#accordion .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#accordion a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b42b2b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#accordion .panel-heading a.collapsed:hover,
#accordion .panel-heading a.collapsed:focus {
  background-color: #b42b2b;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

#accordion .panel-heading a.collapsed:hover::before,
#accordion .panel-heading a.collapsed:focus::before {
  color: white;
}

#accordion .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#accordion .panel-heading a:not(.collapsed) {
  color: white;
  background-color: #b42b2b;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}


/* Add Indicator fontawesome icon to the left */

#accordion .panel-heading .accordion-toggle::before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f00d';
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

#accordion .panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  color: #444;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#panelBodyOne" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Content One</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="panelBodyOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#panelBodyTwo" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Content Two</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="panelBodyTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a href="#panelBodyThree" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Content Three</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="panelBodyThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's better for you to use some plugin like [datatable](https://datatables.net/) to achieve what you want rather than an `accordion`. You just need to declare 1 table, and the data will be split to some pages depending on your total row. You can do search and filter too using that plugin

Comment: Looks like this is not possible with the accordion.